# Windows server 2016 new calculator?

Tags: windows-server-2016, calculator

I'm testing windows server 2016 and I noticed that there is still the old windows 7 calculator. Is there a way to get the new calculator that is in Windows 10? Is this a Desktop experience issue or is it just not in the build?
I goggled but I can't find anything on this topic.

Edit:

Build 1607

Only RDS server role installed

Comment: What roles do you have installed?  You don’t indicate what build you are using (so it’s impossible to answer your question if its included)

Comment: LOL instead I wanted the opposite, the old calculator had more features than the new one, so I wanted to have it on Win 10

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Windows Server rename: `calc.exe` to `calc_old.exe` in the folder `C:\Windows\System32\`
2. Obtain a Windows 10 computer with the correct Calculator application (new Metro design) and copy the file `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe` from it to your other computer into your Window Server's folder `C:\Windows\System32\`

Note: If you have difficulty finding another Windows 10 computer with the metro calc.exe you could try searching online. I have not tested it completely but it opens and works when opened in other non-System32 folders on my own Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it does not work. I think it may be something in the registry.

Comment: @Ruben.w Perhaps troubleshooting compatibility? Try running it directly without shortcuts (if you haven't already).

Comment: Actually, I believe this methodology is naive and likely incorrect. I am going to improve my answer, momentarily.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. If I try this, I get `You'll need a new app to open this ms-calculator`